# Проблема с чтением ChEMBL CSV файлов в Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Итак, у меня есть проблема с чтением csv, взятого с ChEMBL. Есть слухи у моих знакомых, что они сталкивались с подобной проблемой, но раскрывать секреты они не торопятся...

Я должен считать csv с помощью pandas! Но одни файлы считываются весьма каряво, а другие вообще никак!

Я искал решение весь вчерашний день, как новичек, и в итоге кроме как пересохранять через эксель "ручками" не нашёл. Да и задание состоит в том. чтобы я сделал это через питон, а не ручками.

[Вот сами данные](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12oOLUAS3ixGb9xOA_vl6VN93eU7U7ld5)
Как я могу это сделать? Просто покажите, каким образом их можно считать с помощью pandas, и если нужно, с помощью вспомогательных библиотек, методов, которые помогут в итоге получить Pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: 1. если ваша версия pandas содержит [эту ошибку](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18071), то файлы надо предварительно распаковать (если не содержит, используйте опцию `compression='gzip'`). 2. данные внутри находятся в кодировке utf16le (little endian). её надо явно указать: `pandas.read_csv('CHEMBL25-chembl_mechanism_by_parent_target-0ij-I7B6ctduPuf3L53d5PnbEroK07INHApuVrkehVM=.csv',encoding='utf_16_le')`

Comment: Спасибо, с кодировкой я тоже мучился, но файлы, которые вообще не открывали, не открываются и сейчас, например этот 'CHEMBL25-chembl_mechanism_by_parent_target-qASJviqn47ULjGnF8BA0WObN_4CTjdnkB5k-Y1Hphkw=.csv.gz'. Банально выдаёт `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 20 fields in line 5, saw 21`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже подсказал [@aleksandr barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994263/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-chembl-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-pandas/994407#comment1679657_994263) в комментарии, эти файлы сохранены в кодировке *UTF-16 Little Endian*.

Пример с использованием последней версией Pandas (0.24.2):

```
In [34]: fn = r"C:\download\CHEMBL25-chembl_mechanism_by_parent_target-qASJviqn47ULjGnF8BA0WObN_4CTjdnkB5k-Y1Hphkw=.csv.gz"

In [35]: pd.read_csv(fn, encoding="utf-16-le")
Out[35]:
   Molecule ChEMBL ID    Molecule Name   Molecule Type  ...  Mechanism Comment  Selectivity Comment Binding Site Comment
0       CHEMBL1084617       TEMANOGREL  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
1            CHEMBL85      RISPERIDONE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
2            CHEMBL54      HALOPERIDOL  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
3       CHEMBL1215661      PRUVANSERIN  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
4        CHEMBL257704     EPLIVANSERIN  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
5       CHEMBL2110670      VABICASERIN  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
6           CHEMBL564        PROMAZINE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
..                ...              ...             ...  ...                ...                  ...                  ...
38      CHEMBL3187365        ASENAPINE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
39      CHEMBL1201328     CARPHENAZINE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
40      CHEMBL2111101     PIMAVANSERIN  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
41           CHEMBL71   CHLORPROMAZINE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
42          CHEMBL908  CHLORPROTHIXENE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
43          CHEMBL716       QUETIAPINE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []
44          CHEMBL422  TRIFLUOPERAZINE  Small molecule  ...                 []                   []                   []

[45 rows x 20 columns]
```